# insert multiple iptables rules in critical situations

Tags: ubuntu, iptables

I have about 1,500 iptables rules I need to apply just when the server is under attack. It should be easy to remove/add later based on the situation I have. any suggestion for me?
for example it would be acceptable if I could import those rules in 1 line and later comment/uncomment that line. take it easy. I'm actually a programmer :)

Comment: Which firewall service do you use ? ufw ? netfilter-persistent ?

Comment: I'm using ufw. @Dom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. 1500 of similar rules is a very bad idea, because the performance will significantly degraded. Better look at the `ipset` match (it uses hash tables, so this is very fast).
2. Don't use the `ufw`.
3. Run the `iptables-save > current-ruleset.ipv4`.
4. Edit this file and save it under new name (`anti-ddos-ruleset.ipv4`)
5. Check the corectness of your rules with the `iptables-restore -t anti-ddos-ruleset.ipv4` command. Fix errors if present.
6. Now you can atomically load the rules with the `iptables-restore anti-ddos-ruleset.ipv4`.
7. You can apply the new rules with confirmation with the `iptables-apply -t 60 anti-ddos-ruleset.ipv4` command. If you don't confirm the new rule set it will be rolled back to previous version.

Comment: I wanna block all requests from countries other than my own country during DDOS attacks. so according to your first 2 advises what should I do? there are more than 1500 acceptable IP ranges.

Comment: @MahyarDamavand See the other answer.

Answer (score 3):

I second Anton's suggestion, use an ipset. You can create one like so

```
ipset create foo hash:net
```

and then add all your entries

```
ipset add foo 192.168.0.0/24
```

When the need arises you simply let incoming packets match against your set and drop them

```
iptables -A INPUT -m set --set foo src -j DROP
```

Note: All the usual commands like `ipset save` and `ipset restore` work as expected.